# Элемент разметки, реализующий прокрутку содержиого

Tags: android

Подскажите название нужного корневого элемента для создания экрана с возможностью прокрутки.

Объясняю: необходимо разместить на экране большое количество текста и поэтому должна быть возможность прокрутки текста. Скажу сразу- `ListView` не подойдет, так как это список, а мне нужно будет размещать много связного текста и картинки на одном экране.
Пробовал `RelativeLayout`, но текст отображается не корректно, без абзацев.

Подскажите, какой корневой элемент выбрать или возможно что-то указать в свойствах экрана?

Answer (score 2):

ScrollView - наследник GroupView, поддерживающий прокрутку содержимого. 
Еще можно использовать WebView, предварительно оформив(или сгенерировав) контент в HTML формате.

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalScrollView или VerticalScrollView, зависит от направления прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

Как новичок дам ответ понятный новичку

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp" />

</ScrollView>
```